# How to create a report for a specific value of a variable

Tags: sorting, variables, sas

I'm new to SAS and need to produce a report from an existing sas table with the following:

- only show theses variables: var1 var2 var3 var4 month
- only show values for the month 'March'
- only show the 35 first observations

this is what i have for the moment:

```
proc print data= work.table (firstobs=1 obs=35);
    var var1 var2 var3 var4 month;
    
run;
```

i cant figure a way to only show the month of 'march'...

Comment: Welcome. Do you have a Date Variable or do you need to extract the march values from the month column? Is Month a character var?

Comment: Look up the documentation for the `where` statement for `proc print`

Answer (score 0):

In the data set options you can use a where clause, the syntax then depends on the type of the month column, this example will work if it is a character variable:

```
proc print data= work.table (firstobs=1 obs=35 where=(month = 'March'));
```